# horizontal scrolling? javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm looking for a simple method of making a DIV animate horizontally based on anchor points. I'd rather not download an entire library for this if possible...

can anybody suggest any resources for me to learn the inner workings of this?

thanks all:)

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Do you just want a div that has a scrollbar on it, or is there something else setting off the scrolling?  "Anchor points" isn't enough for me to figure out how the scrollbar is controlled.

Comment: Will changing the left position of the DIV will not solve your problem? If not, then please elaborate your question in more details.

Comment: yeah, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap">
    FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO
    FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO
    <span id="a1">BAR!</span>
    FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO
</div>
<a href="#a1">scroll to bar (HTML anchor)</a>
<input type="button" value="scroll to bar (JS scrollIntoView)" />
<input type="button" value="scroll to bar (JS scrollLeft)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var a1= document.getElementById('a1');
    var buttons= document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    buttons[0].onclick= function() {
        a1.scrollIntoView();
    };
    buttons[1].onclick= function() {
        a1.parentNode.scrollLeft= a1.offsetLeft;
    };
</script>
```