# 2 rows of divs inside container div that scrolls only horizontally

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have an image slider that has navigational thumbnails. What I want to do is that the thumbnails will be laid out into 2 rows. Each row having 6 divs (meaning there are 12 divs first shown) and then when there is excess it overflows horizontally and there should be a horizontal scroll. This is related to this question:

[Force horizontal expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743065/force-horizontal-expansion). Only difference is that

I want my divs to display 2 rows instead of one. I've managed to display one row using the solutions given by the above link.

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div id="nav">
      <div id="thumbsWrap">
            <img alt="thumbnail">
            <img alt="thumbnail">
            <img alt="thumbnail"> 
             and so on and so on......
       </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
    #nav{bottom: 26px;height: 128px;left: 108px;overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:hidden;     position: absolute;width: 756px;}
#nav #thumbsWrap{width: auto; white-space: nowrap}
#nav a.thumbs{width:116px; height:95px; background: #4e5b63; display:inline-block; border-radius:8px; margin:6px 10px 0 0;}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only easy way to do this is, add the same div twice.

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="thumbsWrap">
        <img alt="thumbnail">
        <img alt="thumbnail">
        <img alt="thumbnail"> 
        and so on and so on......
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsWrap">
        <img alt="thumbnail">
        <img alt="thumbnail">
        <img alt="thumbnail"> 
        and so on and so on......
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/txCzq/32/

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use the same div twice use a class and not an ID. ID's shouldn't be duplicated especially if JS is using them.