# css horizontal overflow within a div

Tags: html, css, django

So I have a panel, which displays matches from different games. I want the matches to continue horizontally, whether they have room or not. The matches would basically looks like images in a scrolling gallery, where you can then use a horizontal scroll bar to look through them. However, they go to a newline and just get hidden after 3 (total of 930px wide).

HTML/Django:

```
    <div class="panel">
        <!-- tried adding wrapper here -->
        {% for match in all_matches %}
        <div class="match">{{ match.name }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .panel{
        height:160px;
        width:1000px;
        padding-top:5px;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }

    .panel .match{
        height:150px;
        background-color:#c8c8c8;
        width:300px;
        margin-left:10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    /* Tried adding in wrapper, made no difference */
    .panel .wrapper{
        width:1000px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

I've tried a few minor changes, such as overflow to auto/hidden/scroll, width to min-width, display to inline, and so on.. I believe the problem I'm coming down to is that for a wrapper to work, I'd need to know the total width of all matches so that the wrapper is their combined width, but I don't know how to do that since the matches are loaded from django as the page loads.

I also found some other questions similar to this one on Stack Overflow, although I may be implementing them incorrectly, or they just aren't quite what I need.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743065/force-horizontal-expansion.

Comment: The accepted answer for the question above should work. Use an inner <div>  that wraps ".match"es and use white-space: nowrap for it.

Comment: Another example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iokmE

Comment: Yea I had read through that post @TomásGirardiJulio, but I couldn't figure out how to make the wrapper dynamically extend with its contents.. which really I was just lacking was not limiting the wrapper's width. I completely forgot the fact that it would extend as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is neat, but browser support for it is still a little spotty. Fortunately, there's an easier/more well-supported way to handle this. You can get the effect you're after by adding `white-space:nowrap;` to your wrapper, and don't limit its width - that property will prevent the matches from breaking onto a new line, no matter how many there are. You'll only want to limit the width on the panel, not the wrapper.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvparjz4/).

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this problem by making `panel` a flexbox.

```
/* Flexbox-related values */

.panel {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;    
}

.panel .match {
   flex-grow:0;
   flex-shrink:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LLbsyjv/2/

I included the big box to confirm that the items were kept at the desired width of 300 pixels. If you remove `flex-shrink:0` then the items will be automatically resized to be smaller, which is not what you want.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I had never heard of flexboxes before this. I'll have to research them a bit, and thank you very much!